# Как улучшить рекуррентную функцию для вычисления сложного процента?

Tags: javascript, python, java, рекурсия, хороший-тон

Можно ли написать рекуррентную функцию сложного процента лучше.
Вопрос задан для лучшего понимания как используют рекурсию в проектах

Эта функция вычисления сложного процента, изучал статью где в примере был такой код

Основная формула `principalAmount * (1 + interestRate / compoundedPerYear)` и она выполняется рекурсивно такое количество раз, `durationInYears * compoundedPerYear = 120` месяцев (раз)

```js
const durationInYears = 10;
const interestRate = .06;
const compoundedPerYear = 12;
const principalAmount = 4000;

function compoundRecursion(principalAmount, compoundedPerYear, durationInYears, interestRate, numberOfRecursions) {
    let amount, newDuration, totalDuration;

    if (numberOfRecursions === 0) {
        totalDuration = compoundedPerYear * durationInYears;
    } else {
        if (numberOfRecursions !== 0) {
            totalDuration = durationInYears;
        }
    }

    if (durationInYears === 0) {
        return principalAmount;
    } else {
        newDuration = totalDuration - 1;
        amount = principalAmount * (1 + interestRate / compoundedPerYear);
        return compoundRecursion(amount, compoundedPerYear, newDuration, interestRate, 1);
    }
}

console.log(compoundRecursion(principalAmount, compoundedPerYear, durationInYears, interestRate, 0));
```

мне показался такой код, не совсем красивым и по скорости уступающим второму варианту, да и для понимания сложнее, некрасиво потому что начальное значение рекурсии 10 вместо 120

второй вариант такой

```js
const durationInYears = 10;
const interestRate = .06;
const compoundedPerYear = 12;
const principalAmount = 4000;

let totalDuration = compoundedPerYear * durationInYears;
function compoundRecursion(principalAmount, compoundedPerYear, durationInYears, interestRate) {

    if (totalDuration === 0) {
        return principalAmount;
    } else {
        let amount = principalAmount * (1 + interestRate / compoundedPerYear);
        totalDuration = totalDuration - 1;
        return compoundRecursion(amount, compoundedPerYear, totalDuration, interestRate)
    }
}

console.log(compoundRecursion(principalAmount, compoundedPerYear, durationInYears, interestRate))
```

Пожалуйста, если можно расскажите, почему автор статьи использовал первый вариант, вместо второго с выносом переменной за функцию, я чувствую что второй вариант, будет плохо влиять на код, но не знаю из-за малого опыта, так ли это.
Подскажите, может это плохой тон, писать так рекурсию.

Также если есть варианты лучше написать эту формулу именно рекурсивно, очень буду рад ознакомиться. Спасибо!

**UPD:**

Stanislav Volodarskiy, Спасибо большое ему за ответ развернутый, не смотря на то какой был глупый вопрос)

В любом случае, вопрос я изменил для лучшей релевантности в поиске, заголовок изменен был таким:

Плохо ли использовать перезаписываемую переменную за рекурсивной функцией, к чему это может привести?
Ответ: Да. Второй метод, который я написал плохой))

> Новый вариант работает один раз, второй вызов не приводит к ожидаемому результату. Функциональность испорчена. Stanislav Volodarskiy

Comment: Вызовите вашу функцию два раза и объясните почему она не работает второй раз.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy Логично, а как тогда сделать код более лаконичным и быстрым? Запоминается вычисление при первом вызове

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy можно ли как-то сбрасывать значение переменной к начальным значениям после выполнения функции? В любом случае вопрос всё же, в том, правильно ли сделал автор статьи первым методом или есть вариант лучше?))

Comment: а что если let totalDuration = compoundedPerYear * durationInYears; переместить в тело функции? над if

Comment: @Jackson в таком случае, при выполнении первого условия рекурсии, он отдаст duration 119, а затем снова передаст 119 в totalDuration = 12 * 119 = 1428, а должно быть 119 - 1 totalDuration 118 и будет через несколько проходок переполнен стэк

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy подскажите лучше будет, если я задам вопрос так
"Как улучшить эту рекурсию" например, ну более конкретизирую позже? Это не потому что, мне лень делать, это пример из статьи не более, мне хочется более четче разобраться с рекурсией и я действительно не понимаю, неужели нельзя сделать лучше? Если вы могли бы, написать ответ как круче сделать такой пример, ответьте, чтобы не плодить кучу вопросов. Спасибо!

Comment: Терпение, готовлю ответ.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy круто, я думал вы не стали пробовать)) Спасибо!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Функцию станет лучше если понять что интерфейс и рекурсивная реализация требуют разные наборы параметров и разделить функцию на две.

Ваша попытка улучшения провалилась. Старый вариант работал всегда. Новый вариант работает один раз, последующие вызовы не приводят к ожидаемому результату. Функциональность испорчена.

Начать надо с начала. Задача ставится так:

> ```
> principalAmount   - начальная сумма
> interestRate      - годовой процент
> compoundedPerYear - годовой процент начисляется не один раз в год,
>                         а равными частями, это число частей в году
> durationInYears   - сколько лет начислять проценты
>
> проценты должны быть начислены compoundedPerYear * durationInYears раз
> формула для начислений рекуррентная:
>
> amount(0)     = principalAmount
> amount(n + 1) = amount(n) * (1 + interestRate / compoundedPerYear)
> ```

Из постановки задачи вызов функции должен выглядеть так:

```
amount(principalAmount, compoundedPerYear, durationInYears, interestRate)
```

Рекуррентная формула включает число периодов начисления сложных процентов, которых в этом вызове нет. Попытка скрестить интерфейс и реализацию приводит к некрасивому результату. И не надо. Отдельная рекурсивная может выглядеть так:

```
amountRec(principalAmount, compoundedPerYear, interestRate, n)
```

`durationInYears` не используется. Зато есть `n` - сколько раз надо начислить проценты.

Функция `amountRec` - деталь реализации. Спрячем её внутри `amount`:

```
function amount(principalAmount, compoundedPerYear, durationInYears, interestRate) {

    function amountRec(principalAmount, compoundedPerYear, interestRate, n) {
        if (n === 0) {
            return principalAmount;
        }
        return amountRec(principalAmount, compoundedPerYear, interestRate, n - 1) * (1 + interestRate / compoundedPerYear);
    }

    return amountRec(principalAmount, compoundedPerYear, interestRate, compoundedPerYear * durationInYears);
}
```

Первые три аргумента функции `amountRec` одинаковы во всех вызовах. Их можно убрать, значения будут взяты из замыкания:

```
function amount(principalAmount, compoundedPerYear, durationInYears, interestRate) {

    function amountRec(n) {
        if (n === 0) {
            return principalAmount;
        }
        return amountRec(n - 1) * (1 + interestRate / compoundedPerYear);
    }

    return amountRec(compoundedPerYear * durationInYears);
}
```

**P.S.** То что, удобный для пользователя интерфейс не подходит для рекурсии - нормальная ситуация. Большинство рекурсивных функций прячется внутри функций с нормальным интерфейсом.

**P.P.S.** Если думать над задачей дальше, ясно что рекурсия не нужна: вычисляется некоторая степень и умножается на сумму. Так как мы говорим о рекурсии, я этот шаг опускаю.

**P.P.P.S.** Рекурсия - глубокая тема. Почитайте [SICP](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D1%82%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%82%D1%83%D1%80%D0%B0_%D0%B8_%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BF%D1%8C%D1%8E%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC). Есть перевод на русский.

Comment: Очень, очень круто, благодарю, хочу лучше разбираться в рекурсии, ваша рекомендация к изучению отдельная благодарность! Да важно было сделать на рекурсии, а так я понимал, что проще сделать иначе.  Пример автора, возможно был взят для простоты понимания, хотя она намного запутаннее, ваш вариант гораздо более Интуитивен. Ещё раз огромное спасибо за такой развернутый ответ, постараюсь переименовать вопрос, для поиска по лучше